# How to manage memory in this Javascript algorithm?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

My solution to the below problem gives correct answer in the compiler but gets rejected by the online judge due to the following error: JS Allocation failed - process out of memory.
What should I change in my algorithm to get rid of this error?

Codewars Kata:You have to code a function getAllPrimeFactors wich take an integer as parameter and return an array containing its prime decomposition by ascending factors, if a factors appears multiple time in the decomposition it should appear as many time in the array.

exemple:

```
 getAllPrimeFactors(100) returns [2,2,5,5] in this order.
```

This decomposition may not be the most practical.

You should also write getUniquePrimeFactorsWithCount, a function which will return an array containing two arrays: one with prime numbers appearing in the decomposition and the other containing their respective power.

exemple:

```
getUniquePrimeFactorsWithCount(100) returns [[2,5],[2,2]]
```

You should also write getUniquePrimeFactorsWithProducts an array containing the prime factors to their respective powers.

exemple:

```
getUniquePrimeFactorsWithProducts(100) returns [4,25]
```

Errors, if:

n is not a number
n not an integer
n is negative or 0
The three functions should respectively return

```
 [], [[],[]] and [].
```

Edge cases:

```
if n=0, the function should respectively return [], [[],[]] and [].
if n=1, the function should respectively return [1], [[1],[1]], [1].
if n=2, the function should respectively return [2], [[2],[1]], [2].
```

The result for n=2 is normal. The result for n=1 is arbitrary and has been chosen to return a usefull result. The result for n=0 is also arbitrary but can not be chosen to be both usefull and intuitive.

```
([[0],[0]]
```

would be meaningfull but wont work for general use of decomposition,

```
[[0],[1]]
```

would work but is not intuitive.)

Here is my algorithm:

```
function getAllPrimeFactors(n) { 
    var fact=[];
    while(n%2===0)
    {
        fact.push(2);
        n=n/2;
    }
    var i=3;
    while(i<=Math.floor(Math.sqrt(n)))
    {
        while(n%i===0)
        {
            fact.push(i);
            n=n/i;
        }
        i++;
    }

    if(n>2)
    {
        fact.push(n);
    }

    return fact;
}

function getUniquePrimeFactorsWithCount(n) { 
    var fact=getAllPrimeFactors(n);
    var i=0;
    var count=[];
    var unique=[];
    var c=0;
    while(i<fact.length)
    {
        if(fact[i]===fact[i+1])
        {
            c++;
        }
        else
        {
            count.push(c+1);
            c=0;
            unique.push(fact[i]);
        }
        i++;
    }

    var fact_count=[];
    fact_count.push(unique);
    fact_count.push(count);
    return fact_count;
}

function getUniquePrimeFactorsWithProducts(n) { 
    var fact_count=getUniquePrimeFactorsWithCount(n);
    var fact_prod=[];
    var i=0;
    while(i<fact_count[0].length)
    {
        var prod=1;
        var j=1;
        while(j<=fact_count[1][i])
        {
            prod*=fact_count[0][i];
            j++;
        }
        fact_prod.push(prod);
        i++;
    }
    return fact_prod;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a sample input data for the 'out of memory' case?

Comment: @Georgy No.The online judge passes all the cases but fails the solution as it says that it takes more than 600ms to run the solution so it terminated

Comment: It's interesting. They can give you really big number, prime one, or a very large set of numbers and you would try to find factorization for ages. It's also strange that they say `This decomposition may not be the most practical`. Mathematically speaking this statement means nothing here. You'd better ask them through the help center. Also try to check for 0 input. Wild guess, but why not?)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you enter an endless loop if you are passed 0.  You should make 0 and negatives into special cases.

Comment: There is an input condition which says that the input is greater than 0

Comment: @Varun Where is that input condition stated?  The spec says what input is invalid, and what to return if you're passed invalid input.  You should expect test cases where you are passed invalid input to see if you do the right thing.  Right now you don't.